# Will code-push react-native override the iOS version and deploy an older push to newer version?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, code-push, react-native-code-push

Lets say I have an iOS app version 5.0 and deploy a code push update. Then I make a new app version 5.1, it appears that old update is still being applied to the new version 5.1

Is this expected behavior? How can I get code-push to deploy only to the older version (5.0) and not anything higher?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `--targetBinaryVersion` flag for code-push cli. So in your case it would be something like

```
code-push release-react MyApp-iOS ios --targetBinaryVersion "5.0"
```

There are many options as of which versions you can target for each deploy, make sure to check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/cli#target-binary-version-parameter for more options

Answer (score 0):

Problem with Codepush is that when you make a release of your app through code-push . code-push stores your app bundle at its server. so whenever code-push detect a difference in your local app(older or latest) and the copy stored at server it gives an update notification.so whenever you making a version change,or change in code, in your app make sure to update code-push server build as well.otherwise it will gives update popup every time.